# using sed or grep to split a url

Tags: bash, sed, grep

For instance , I have a url like this --> `http://google.com/test/to_be_extracted.html` I want to split this url and get `to_be_extracted` part only. I want to exclude `http://google.com/test/` and `.html` parts.

How can I setup regex pattern using GREP or SED ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$ echo 'http://google.com/test/to_be_extracted.html' | sed -r 's#.*\/([^.]+).*#\1#'
to_be_extracted
```

#### Breakdown:

```
sed -r '          # -r switch enables Extended Regular expressions   
s                 # Using substitution flag
#                 # Using # as delimiter since you have `/` in your lines
.*\/              # Match everything greedily until you see last `/`. 
([^.]+)           # Create a capture group to capture everything until you see a literal .
.*                # Followed by everything else
#                 # Another delimiter
\1                # Print the captured group
#'                # Final delimiter
```

Comment: Yes, it's working! Thanks, can you please explain your regex pattern a bit, I am very new at regex.

Comment: @Ibrahim Added the explanation. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the solution to involve unnecessary tools?

```
basename "$url" .html
```

will do what you require, trivially and transparently.

Comment: Actually, what I am trying to archive my goal is like , `echo 'http://google.com/test/to_be_extracted.html' | sed 's/*www.google.com/test//' ` but this code only returning this `/to_be_extracted.html ` I don't want `/ and .html` .